# syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Tags: c++, makefile

After compiling some code using a `Makefile` I get this when I try to run it:

```
$ ./libbookgui.a
./libbookgui.a: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./libbookgui.a: line 1: `!<arch>'
```

The `Makefile` has the following contents.

```
INCLUDES = -I"$(FLTK)"
LIBS     = -lstdc++
CXXFLAGS = $(INCLUDES) -Wall -time -O3 -DNDEBUG -Wno-deprecated
LIBFLAGS = 
AR       = ar

.SUFFIXES: .cpp .o

# Create a list of source files.
SOURCES  = $(shell ls *.cpp)
# Create a list of object files from the source file lists.
OBJECTS = ${SOURCES:.cpp=.o}     
# Create a list of targets.
TARGETS = libbookgui.a

# Build all targets by default
all:    $(TARGETS)

%.a: $(OBJECTS)
    $(AR) rcs $@ $(OBJECTS)

# A rule to build .o file out of a .cpp file
%.o: %.cpp 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

# A rule to clean all the intermediates and targets
clean:  
    rm -rf $(TARGETS) $(OBJECTS) *.out *.stackdump
```

I see that it has the line `TARGETS = libbookgui.a` and the compiler doesn't return any errors it just creates the `.a` file.

Any ideas?

Comment: `.a` is a library archive, it is not an executable.

Answer (score 1):

`libbookgui.a` is a static library (that aggregates several object files in it).

You are supposed to run executables, not libraries. Link this library into some executable and run *that*.

I suggest you read [this article](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html).

Comment: I see, during the link process (`cc -o executable-name libctest.a`) the compiler returns errors such as: `libbookgui.a(Store_main.o):Store_main.cpp:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to Fl_Menu_::Fl_Menu_(int, int, int, int, char const*)'` or `libbookgui.a(Store_main.o):Store_main.cpp:(.text+0x461): undefined reference to std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'`

Comment: @ignacio: this is a different problem now - some symbols `libctest.a` is looking for should be found in other libraries, so you should link those as well. Also you'll need a `main` from somewhere. I really think you should start with something very small and simple and make it work first - the step you're taking here is way too big for a start

Comment: It appears that I forgot to link my source files. (.cpp) But now the compiler returns `/tmp/ccLGb4Ui.o:Chrono.cpp:(.text+0x306): undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)'` I am using the Chrono class from [Stroustrup's programming site.](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Programming-code.zip)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your post to show the changes you made to the makefile to get the link line added.  Without that we can't really help you with that part of the problem.

Based on the errors my suspicion is that you're not using the right tool for linking: you're either using "gcc" (C compiler front-end) or trying to invoke the linker directly.  When you link your application you should use the C++ compiler (in your case, `$(CXX)`).  You also don't need to specify `-lstdc++`, since the C++ front-end will automatically add that to the link line.